# How to stop scroll when dynamic div ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I want to stop scroll after a dynamic div reaches its end. This div will be holding dynamic content so the size never stays the same. I know how to lock in position when scroll hits a pre-defined height, but not sure how to do it when the hight is constantly changing. here's what i'm using for my standard locking scroll when it hits specific point:

```
var profile_rc = $("#profile-rc");
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 285) {
        profile_rc.addClass("p-right-column");
    } else {
        profile_rc.removeClass("p-right-column");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using jQuery, the following 2 examples might help.

Detecting dynamic height of screen

```
<script>

$(function(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        windowHeight = $(window).height();
        console.log(windowHeight);
    });
});
<script>
```

Detecting dynamic height of a div

```
<script>
$(function(){

    var divHeight = $('#your-div-id').css("height");

    $( window ).on("resize", function() {
       divHeight = $('#your-div-id').css("height");
       console.log(divHeight);
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work doing this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var divHeight = $('#farleft-cont').outerheight(true);
var ycbc = $('#target-div');
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (scroll >= divHeight) {
ycbc.addClass("target-div-fixed");
} else {
ycbc.removeClass("target-div-fixed");
}
});
```